# Truly befuddling comorbidity of AMD GPU video issues that seem specific to Windows 11

Tags: windows, video, multiple-monitors, gpu, amd-radeon

So, I have two issues that *seem* to be related, but I'm unsure. Any advice from those more wise than I is appreciated, but I know my way around Windows and hardware stuff plenty well.

So:

- When the computer is launched and also just... randomly when changing around video settings, my main monitor is incredibly dark *but not the cursor*. I have no clue how this could be happening. I've looked and it's no night light thing, but it's fixed by disconnecting and reconnecting the monitor in any manner, including toggling settings in Adrenalin. Seen in video attached.
- More annoyingly, one of my two monitors that *aren't primary* (almost always the same one) become... laggy? Video attached of the phenomena. Usage on all cores is low, and the same for the GPU. This is *also* remedied by toggling random settings like VSR and GPU Scaling, but it's... unreliable. I often have to do it once every few hours, and it takes a few tries. [This isn't a refresh rate thing, I know what sixty feels like and this is like twenty]

Attempted fixes mostly include digging around in any video menu imaginable, trying to set my main monitor to 120 instead of 144, et cetera. Attempted changing color profile manually using builtin Windows ones on main monitor as well.

I have no idea what's causing either. Image and video of either are attached, and I'm at my wit's end. This is new to Windows 11, it didn't happen when I was on 10.

Video: https://mega.nz/file/iUdADSKI#ncGlC-l8ezUB-OLhnyhShVr8PzjeFAI7sdDfnNr6LVM

Comment: Did you look for and install the Windows 11 Driver for your machine?   Get the manufacturer's Driver Update App and install / run it. Install all it says to install. Do a final restart and test.

Comment: We can’t tell what your clicking on. A static screenshot would be helpful. This seems like a monitor problem though.

Comment: Above solution didn't work, and as to the second it's as I said - literally just mashing "Virtual Super Resolution" and "GPU Scaling" in settings until it just... works. Before this video was taken, I turned it on and off three times, so it's just... random. I'll try doing a *full* reinstall of AMD drivers using DDU, see if that helps, and report back. The thing that messes with me is that this video seems to be capturing windows at 30fps, even though the monitor is showing 15 until I fix it. Seems to me like a GPU issue, but I'm unsure. https://youtu.be/deQ986T2__Y